# How to host two website on different ports with Tp-link modem port forwarding?

Tags: ip, port, modem

my tp-link modem control panel is the old version. I wanna forward "modem-public-ip:80" to "192.168.1.105" and "modem-public-IP:9090" to "192.168.1.103".
I've applied this setting:
[image]

The first one is ok and its running on "modem-public-IP:80" , but the second one is not working.

both of my services are running on port 80 of their internal IP. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions that comes to my mind:

1. you can try to set the "Local IP address" to 192.168.0.103:80 but I think it'll go in error
2. Try to find "static NAPT" on modem configuration, there you'd should be able to specify the local port
3. you can put the web server ".103" listening on port 9090